# Cygwin's "source" command fails when installing package

Tags: cygwin

I am using cygwin to compile the source code on Windows from this website

https://github.com/davidstutz/extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark/tree/master/source

```
To compile the benchmarking software from source code, run:

   source build.sh

This script should compile the correspondPixels mex file and copy it into the 
../benchmarks/ directory.
```

But the following commands I typed do not work. I am in the folder directory.

```
$ source build.sh
-bash: build.sh: No such file or directory

$ ./source build.sh
-bash: ./source: Is a directory

$ ls
asa.mat     others               relabel.m            tests
benchmarks  plot_benchmarks.asv  source               use.mat
data        plot_benchmarks.m    test_benchmarks.asv
LICENSE.md  README.md            test_benchmarks.m
```

This is my first time using Cygwin so the commands are new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build.sh` file is in the `source` directory.

```
$ cd source
$ source build.sh
```

(Don't confuse the directory name `source` with the shell's built-in command `source`.)

You can also use `. build.sh` rather than `source build.sh`; the `.` command is equivalent to `source`, and probably a bit more conventional.